# iOS determine data length of CBCharacteristic

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

Is there any way to dynamically sniff out the data length of a CBCharacteristic?

I'm evolving the characteristic API on a gadget I have, and I want to change the field width of one of the characteristics. If I make the change in the iOS side so that it writes a value of 9 bytes instead of 7 bytes, a device that has the old API (characteristic field width of 7) on it causes the following to occur when I attempt to write the value:

```
Error Domain=CBATTErrorDomain Code=13 "The value's length is invalid." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The value's length is invalid.}
```

What I'd like to determine is whether or not I can catch that error, and then somehow query the CBCharacteristic what its current field width is. Obviously at some point, it determined that `9 > 7` and caused the error to bubble up. I've tried reading the descriptor associated with the characteristic, but there's just one descriptor (`<CBDescriptor: 0x2830cbe40, UUID = Client Characteristic Configuration, value = 2>`) which doesn't tell me much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a standard ATT protocol error that's generated by the peripheral, not iOS. It means you sent a value and the peripheral responded that the value was the wrong length. Characteristics do not necessarily have specific lengths. The correct length might be context dependent. For example, a characteristic might accept 2 bytes, 4 bytes, or 8 bytes. If you write 7 bytes, it could return this error. Or the first byte might be a command selector, and the rest might be the payload that needs to be of a specific length for that command. There's no simple "what's the length of this characteristic" for these designs.

There's no general way to know what a remote service wants. You need to know that through API documentation. This is the equivalent of getting back a `405 Method not allowed` error from an HTTP server. It's up to you to know what methods are allowed. A particular system might give you a way to query it, and it might not. It's not part of the HTTP spec to provide that, and similarly it's not part of the BLE spec.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. I worried this would be the case. I'm using a ST-BLUENRG chip on the gadget side, and it's ACI protocol (which is a simplified GATT/GAP API) takes a field width for gatt definitions. So it must be catching and raising the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the maximum packet length allowed by a characteristic with
peripheral.maximumWriteValueLength(for:CBCharacteristicWriteType.<>)